# How could I add attributes to <option> tags using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

```
// Doing this:
$e = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('combo');
$e->addMultiOptions(array(1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb'));
$e->renderViewHelper();

// I'll get something like this;
<select name="combo" id="combo">
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
</select>
```

How could I add attributes to  tags using Zend Framework?

```
// I mean, I wanna get something like this:
<select name="combo" id="combo">
  <option abc="123" value="1">Jan</option>
  <option abc="456" value="2">Feb</option>
</select>
```

Comment: see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8684

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to create your own class extending Zend_Form_Element

Answer (score 0):

The helper that builds the HTML for the Zend_Form_Element_Select is Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect. This helper builds the  elements in the _build function. This function only creates  tags with the following attributes:

- value
- label
- selected
- disabled

If you would like more options you would need to create your own form element with your own helper for rendering. I would suggest overriding the existing ones and just changing this specific part.

Kind regards,

Robin